# What is matter made of in the light of Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, energy, waves, matter

I've always wondered what matter (particles, force particles, etc.) was actually made of considering the fact that quantum mechanics has shown us that particles can actually act as a probabilistic wave.  But the question would then remain, what **is** matter made of in that case if it's able to be in different forms according to quantum mechanics?  Could it possibly just be energy?  Or is there something more?

Comment: Can you explain what matter is made out of *not* in light of quantum mechanics? The word effective means "the stuff stuff is made out of". It's the answer not the question.

Answer (score 1):

As dmckee's comment says, your question doesn't really have an answer. However it's exactly the sort of question that fascinated me in my time as a teenage physics enthusiast, and I think it touches on some really interesting aspects of physics. To get a grip on this you need to understand how matter is described by [quantum field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory). This is not necessarily the ultimate description of matter, as we expect some deeper theory such as string theory will eventually supercede QFT. But even if/when this happens we expect QFT to remain a good low energy approximation.

Actually you've anticipated the answer when you ask:

> Could it possibly just be energy?

I have to be careful saying that matter is the same as energy, lest I [incur the wrath of the purists](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/mass-in-special-relativity-misconception). However the answer is that, yes, matter is basically just energy. I'll spend the rest of this answer attempting to justify this and explain what I mean by it.

The word *energy* tends to be used rather loosely. Here I mean it as a property of some physical system. For example a guitar string has energy when it's vibrating. You make the guitar string vibrate by adding energy to it, and the guitar string can stop vibrating by losing energy.

Quantum field theory describes the fundamental particles of matter, like electrons, as excitations in a quantum field. There is a quantum field for every fundamental particle, for example there is an electron field. These quantum fields pervade all of spacetime. You need to be cautious about the physical interpretation of quantum fields because they are not like the analogy of a guitar string that I mentioned above. A quantum field is an operator field. Its physical interpretation is a somewhat vexed issue - I'm not sure there is any agreement on the physical interpretation, though I am sure I don't understand it.

Anyhow, electrons are excitations of the electron quantum field. Adding energy to the field creates an electron and electrons can be destroyed by transferring energy away from the field. Incidentally, this explains how particles like the Higgs boson can be created in accelerators. The kinetic energy of the colliding particles can be transferred into excitations of various quantum fields where it appears as particles. It also explains how matter can turn into energy in nuclear reactions. A quantum field can transfer energy into the kinetic energy of the reaction products, and the result is that a particle disappears and its energy turns into kinetic energy.

The point of all this is that matter is energy in the form of excitations of quantum fields. This is the nearest I know to an answer to the question *what is matter*.

The usual caveats apply: the description I've given is a drastic oversimplification, and to be honest this is an area I myself only understand vaguely.